# How to get the information that the update was used in the trigger?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a trigger that gets the information when the user deletes or modifies the payment method insert the D for deleted and M for modified, the is being used in the trigger o for DELETE, update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_forpag_Drop]
on [dbo].[CUPONS2]
for DELETE, update 
as
BEGIN

 

DECLARE @seqecf                INT, 
        @seqecf2            INT,
        @CODFORPAG            INT,
        @NOMOPERADORES        INT,
        @isDelivery         char(1),
        @Data                datetime,
        @status             char(1)

 

SELECT @seqecf = deleted.SEQECF, @CODFORPAG = deleted.CODFORPAG FROM DELETED 
SELECT @nomoperadores = codope, @isDelivery = cupdelivery FROM CUPONS WHERE SEQECF = @SEQECF
if @isDelivery = 'S' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
insert into forpagdel (seqecfforpagdel, codope, datforpagdel, codforpagdel, movstat) select deleted.seqecf, @nomoperadores, getDate(), deleted.codforpag, 'D' from DELETED
else IF exists (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
insert into forpagdel (seqecfforpagdel, codope, datforpagdel, codforpagdel, movstat) select seqecf, @nomoperadores, getDate(), codforpag, 'M' from update
END
```

And the return of SQL is this:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Trg_forpag_Drop, Line 24 [Batch 7 Start Line]
Incorrect syntax next to the 'update' keyword.

Is it possible to get the information when the update is used?

Note: I tested it with inserted, but it ends up NULL the `codope` field because its select comes from a `deleted`

Comment: **WARNING:** Your trigger is fatally flawed; it *assumes* that a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` can only ever effect 1 row. This this simply not true, as they can affect 0+ rows. [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: For both update and delete triggers, the virtual DELETED table will always contain rows if any row was affected by the actual DML statement. So your logic will generally invoke the IF block and not the ELSE IF block. I suggest you first write separate triggers for the update and delete actions (after fixing the single-row flaw), get those working correctly, and THEN combine them if needed.

Comment: See also https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/